# Why normalized EXR renderings of surface Normals look different than PNG renderings?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering, normals, .exr

I render surface Normals using Cycles and store the results in EXR format. The values in the EXR format are within the range of `[-1, 1]` meaning that I cannot directly store the values in a PNG file. Here's how I read the `.exr` files and store store the values in a `numpy` array:

```
import OpenEXR, array, Imath
exrFile = OpenEXR.InputFile('normal.exr')
FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
(RGB) = [array.array('f', exrFile.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G", "B") ]
normalNPArray = np.array(RGB)
normalNPArray = normalNPArray.reshape((3, resolution, resolution))
```

I normalize the values as follow and store the surface Normal as a PNG image:

```
normalNPArray += 1
normalNPArray /= 2
normalNPArray *= 255
normalNPArray = normalNPArray.astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(normalNPArray.transpose(1, 2, 0), mode='RGB')
im.save('temp.png')
```

Here's what I get after opening the stored image:
[image]

If I simply ignore the values below zero (remove/comment the first two lines) I get the following:
[image]

However, if I directly store the surface Normal as a PNG image instead of EXR I get the following:

[image]

I wonder, how can I get a visualization that looks like the PNG rendering? How does Blender normalize the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Numpy does not automatically set the negative values to `0` when casting the array type to `uint8`. For instance, suppose I have a numpy array as follow:

```
array([  46.73017823, -250.31618571, -247.44416527,   97.52841554,
       -204.92988386,  191.09452493,  103.15708521,  -86.10470495,
         46.211924  , -195.30653599,  240.44499889, -169.42729244,
        210.44996545, -182.04892973, -166.20581924, -221.11524425,
        164.79367242, -199.80888341,   94.1786936 ,   43.45477102])
```

I was expecting that doing `normalNPArray = normalNPArray.astype(np.uint8)` will automatically set the negative values to `0` since `uint8` does not naturally support negative values. However, casting the array as `np.uint8` gives me the following:

```
array([ 46,   6,   9,  97,  52, 191, 103, 170,  46,  61, 240,  87, 210,
            74,  90,  35, 164,  57,  94,  43], dtype=uint8)
```

Doing `normalNPArray[normalNPArray < 0] = 0` and then casting the array to `np.uint8` will resolve the issue.